# What was the monster in Deep Rising supposed to be?

Tags: b-movies, deep-rising

If it is nothing more than "generic monster cooked up for bad B-movie", I can settle for that. Please provide an explanation of how it can only be such.

If there is more to it (and the characters do hint at it in a few places in the movie) please explain it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Rising

Wikipedia says that the thing is a member of a genus of sea worms, but this thing has eyes, a beak, and tentacles which, apparently, have mouths at the end. I do not think this counts as a general reference, since it *clearly* cannot be correct.

And don't even get me started about the island at the end.

No good images are available of the boss creature, but here is the best I could find: the head with the eyes is roughly the size of a small apartment:

[image]

Izkata also found these [pictures of the smaller ones](http://www.vfxhq.com/1998/deeprising.html):

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Are the images here](http://www.vfxhq.com/1998/deeprising.html) shots from the movie or just possible versions from before the movie was released?

Comment: dude,I am pretty sure in the movie they deduced it is an Ottoia.. Giant mutated one though.. The modus operandi and description matches.. Plus the characters themselves speculate it.. Posted my findings as answer as well..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The creature in Deep Rising is a giant mutant octopus. If you watch the scene in the gallery, Treat Williams actually tells a story about putting a fish in a jar then closing the lid, giving it to an  octopus which was able to open the jar and climb in and consume the fish. To which Famke Janssen replies "we're the fish".

Comment: I am not 100% certain you are correct, but I find the answer plausible. You deserve the rep for this, marking it accepted.

Comment: i think the octopus thing is a metaphor, Canton deduces the monster as an offshoot of Ottoia family.. tells it himself after the captain of the ship dies..

Answer (score 6):

Borrowed from [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100106225050AAA5YFC) (3 years ago - looks like it's since been removed from Wikipedia):

> Courtesy of Wikipedia:
> It is revealed that the ship has become infested by creatures that resemble giant worms, which swallow and digest their prey alive. Canton speculates that they are members of the Ottoia family of deep-sea worms which have evolved to immense size in the extreme depths of oceanic trenches.
>
> However, the summary goes on to say this:
> Finnegan and Trillian discover that the creatures are actually the tentacles of a much larger octopus-like sea monster.
>
> When I checked up on Ottoia, I found this:
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoia
> So, it looks as if they based their monster on the prehistoric creature. I've always been curious about the Ottoia, but I never stopped to look it up before. So, we're left to wonder if this is a separate sea creature or a really enormous example of the other animal mentioned.

Aaand courtesy of Wikipedia, this is a reconstruction of an Ottoia in its burrow:
[image: Ottoia drawing]

---

Additionally, [eHow](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913143401/http://www.ehow.com/info_8078230_were-creatures-deep-rising-movie.html) suggests it was at least partially based off of H.P. Lovecraft's mythos.

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious as well, but I found one possible source for the creatures design.

[image]

Comment: That is interesting, and does look vaguely like the creatures depicted. Thanks for the link. If you have a name (or even a genus) for the organism, please edit it in.

Comment: @JohnO The creature in the gif is identified in [marcus's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40341/1359): it is a bobbit worm, *eunice aphroditois*.

Answer (score 3):

Well finally found some dialogues of the movie --

> **Canton**: [Captain Atherton has just been eaten by one of the monsters]
>   I'm beginning to fear that our friends here may be some kind of
>   strange off-shoot of the Archaea Ottoia family.
>
> **Pantucci**: ***The Ottoia family? To think I was startin' to worry***.
>
> **Canton**: These creatures are actually part of a larger body...
>   something we haven's seen yet. They live deep under the surface of any
>   ocean. At 4,000 feet the Ottoia are only as long as a pencil, with
>   bodies about the size of a golf ball. But those at 20,000 feet have
>   been known to eat full grown sharks! At 30,000 or 40,000 feet...
>
> [to Pantucci]
>
> **Canton**: Well... you do the math.
>
> **Trillian St. James**: This is not good.
>
> **Pantucci**: Are we talkin' some kind of mutated sea monsters here?
>
> **Mason**: Who gives a shit what they are? Just tell us how to kill these
>   motherfuckers.
>
> **Canton**: The Ottoia are very crafty. They hide in burrows. They catch
>   their victims with spiny living tentacles. Then they crush them
>   between massive jaws.
>
> **Trillian St. James**: Then they eat you, right?
>
> **Canton**: No, they drink you. They drink you alive. Sucking all the
>   fluids out of the body before excreting the skeletal remains.

And this is exactly how we see the monsters killing the targets.

**So my answer is MUTATED OTTOIA...**

Answer (score 2):

I think it was modelled off a bobbit worm "eunice aphroditois". The attack style and speed etc are very similar and they reckon they can grow to 3M long

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be at least two creatures; Joey is chased off the boat at the same time Finnigan is fighting the big one in the banquet hall. Also of note is that the tentacle that eats Hanover seems to taper down toward the rear as if it were a worm. My best speculation is that the large adults spawn by parthenogenesis, growing smaller clones as tentacles until they are big enough to break free and move about on their own like the one that got Hanover.

Comment: Speculative, but thoughtful. If so, though, does this suggest that the giant octopoid in the banquet hall is a mature specimen, and its own tentacles are budding off the smaller worm creatures shown elsewhere throughout the movie, is that what you mean? Or do you mean two different species?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be something invented entirely for the film, albeit inspired by bobbit worms and the works of H.P. Lovecraft.  The "Ottoia" references Canton pulls out of thin air are a red herring, and it can't be an actual cephalopod because they don't have mouths in their tentacles, don't drain their prey's fluids, have pupils in their eyes, and have beaks rather than teeth.

Answer (score 1):

The Ottoi and Bobbit wyrm are two creatures but mutated into one ,theory: the bombing testing in Asian waters( spoiler Godzilla Area ) radiotherapy gave new DNA growth to the creatures(jaws is said to be a Asian great white will link sources ) a scuttle fish or ottoiwas devoured by a bobbit wyrm during test, granted mutation for 20 years or so 
Theory to be the orgin of known monsters blockbuster